# SSAS Tabular - Multiple Models?

Tags: ssas, tabular, ssas-tabular

We're starting to build an SSAS tabular model and wondering if most people have one model or multiple.  If multiple, do you duplicate tables that are needed by each, or is there a way to share tables between models?  I think I know the answer, but I'm hoping those with more experience can confirm what we've found...

From what I've researched I think...
 - you can't share tables across models - any "common" tables would have to be duplicated in and deployed with each model and would take up memory
 - we should create one model, use perspectives to organize the tables and make it easier to work with
 - multiple models could be acceptable if there is little or no common data across models

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct, there is no way to share tables between models.

Perspectives can help.

The question of whether to have one model or more depends on the user audience. Who are the users? How analytically savvy are they? Will they have a reasonable understanding of the model structure?

One issue that affects my rather unsophisticated users is when a dimension does not relate to all fact tables. In this scenario, as is expected, measures on the fact table calculate identical values for every member of the unrelated dimension. For less knowledgeable users, this situation is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Ari's answer, and am posting this answer to explain my own experience.

We use a few large models for more sophisticated users that are in memory and processed once a week. We have agreed with the business that these models will not be available during processing, so we are able to processes without holding a transaction open which allows us to keep many more smaller models because we do not need to keep 2x the size of our largest model available to the instance. We use perspectives to simplify the presentation and reduce the confusion for the multiple fact tables. Even with perspectives, the models are rather complex, and it takes some training to get users used to working with the different facts.

We also use smaller models, usually more targeted to a specific audience/need. Many are processed daily, and use transactional processing to ensure the are available to users as much as possible. There are several dimensions that are used in several of our small models, but we are able to filter them so that user's do not see the full list of members which reduces size, and has been a huge benefit for my users, because they only see members that have a fact that they are analyzing instead of a list of every member associated with any fact.

We use views to ensure conformity between models when a dimension is used in multiple models. In my opinion this is very important, as it is very confusing when I have the same dimension with slightly different attribute names.

To sum up (pun intended)...

I like developing and working with large models. I think they answer more questions with less work.

Most users I have worked with prefer smaller, more concise models. Your server hardware/processing requirements may direct you to smaller models as well, even though some of the dimensions will be duplicated.